# Read strings for filtering data from an input file

Tags: powershell

I have pulled all disabled users properties into text file called "`Disable.txt`". Now I want to exclude users from specific OU's called `Collaboration accounts`, `Security Principles` & `Service Accounts`. I was able to do the following way.

```
Select-String 'OU=Collaboration accounts', 'OU=Security Principles', 'OU=Service Accounts' $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\DisabledUsers.txt -NotMatch | % {$_.Line} | Set-Content $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\DisableList.txt
```

But I have been asked exclusion OU's should be picked from an input file.
 So I tried to create a text file with content `'OU=Collaboration accounts', 'OU=Security Principles', 'OU=Service Accounts'` and assigned to variable and then to be called.
But this is not working. Could anybody suggest the alternate way?

Comment: can you provide an user example to reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide those filter strings as an array. If you put a literal line

```
'OU=Collaboration accounts', 'OU=Security Principles', 'OU=Service Accounts'
```

into the input file it and read that, it will be passed to `Select-String` as a single string like this:

```
Select-String "'OU=Collaboration accounts', 'OU=Security Principles', 'OU=Service Accounts'" ...
```

Instead, put each filter string on a separate line (without commas or quotes).

```
OU=Collaboration accounts
OU=Security Principles
OU=Service Accounts
```

`Get-Content` will read the file as a string array with each line as a separate array element:

```
$filters = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.txt'
Select-String $filters ...
```